# Где хранится шаблон редактирования товара Opencart?

Tags: php, opencart, cms, twig

Нужно отредактировать страницу редактирования товара. добавить ещё одно поле, но не могу найти шаблон с этой страницей. [image: На изображении та самая страница которую нужно изменить]

Answer (score 0):

За страницу создания/редактирования товара отвечает файл

```
/admin/view/template/catalog/product_form.twig
```

Но это только отображение. Надо править и контроллер:

```
/admin/controller/catalog/product.php
```

И файл модели:

```
/admin/model/catalog/product.php
```